# How to send Crypto payments (programmatically) gotten through coinbase commerce

Tags: django, e-commerce, coinbase-api, django-4.0

i have successfully integrated coinbase commerce into my django app for receiving cryptocurrency payment from the users. However the site payment process involves receiving payment from a **User A** which is intended for **User B** into the site ***coinbase commerce wallet*** and then only after **User B** has completely handed over whatever was the value/asset been paid for, then the payment would go on to be forwarded finally to **User B.**

But the issue is that coinbase commerce has no facility for sending payments. and though payment can be sent with a python api on COINBASE, they are two seperate things and the money/coin in coinbase commerce would not be accessible from COINBASE even if it the same user/profile on the platform.

Please does anyone have a solution to this problem...even if it does not use coinbase commerce, the only requirement is that it uses a *crypto payment gateway*

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same stage with you, I think there is no such thing in commerce Coinbase but if you take a look at the Coinbase developer api you can see transfer money endpoint under the transactions title: https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money But I couldn't understand why we need to have account_id, I just want to transfer money from my own account to users. You can also take a look at Coinbase Pro api, there may be something helpful for us.

Comment: yes i see what you are saying here, but then the money in the coinbase commerce wallet can not be access with the coinbase API